# NFA has power to be in several states at once implies NFA has ability to guess about its input. How?

Tags: finite-automata, terminology

[image]

I agree that NFA has power to be in several states at once. It probably means that on same input, NFA can be on multiple states. But what I can't understand is how can we conclude from this that "NFA has ability to guess about its input". What is this trying to say? Can you explain with example using NFA rather than the one used by hopcroft book.

Comment: Don't use an image of text or mathematics.  This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Also, we require you to provide proper attribution for the source of that material.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to "guess" is an informal but often helpful analogy on the NFA's capability to solve problems with much fewer states than the equivalent DFA would. I will demonstrate with an example.

Let $L_n = \{ w \in \{a, b\}^* : \text{the } n\text{th-last character of } w \text{ is } a\}$.

For example, $L_1$ is the language of strings with $a$ as the final character, $L_2$ is the language of strings with $a$ as the second-from-last character, etc.

For every fixed $n$, $L_n$ is regular and therefore a DFA accepts it. It is fairly simple to create these DFAs for small values of $n$: for example, when $n=2$ you only need four states: one for each possible sequence of two characters (the last two that were read, with the initial state also being served by the state $bb$). States representing $aa$ and $ab$ are accepting.

However, these automata grow very fast with $n$: you need $2^n$ states, to be exact, match $L_n$ with DFA. Let's approach the problem with an NFA.

The NFA, instead of having to maintain a record of $n$ symbols all the time, can "guess", whenever it sees an $a$ symbol, that this $a$ is the $n$th to last symbol of the string. The NFA will look like this for $n=3$:

```
(q0, a OR b) -> q0
(q0, a) -> q1
(q1, a OR b) -> q2
(q2, a OR b) -> q_accept
```

The NFA will always be in the initial state $q_0$, and when it encounters an $a$, it will also launch a "guess" at $q_1$. If this $a$ indeed was the $n$th last character, this "guess" will be in the state $q_{accept}$ after reading two more characters. Since the NFA is always in the state $q_0$, each $a$ launches a similar guess and multiple "guesses" can occur in parallel, eg. if there are successive $a$ symbols in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: the language of all words over $\{a,b,c\}$ which *do not* contain all letters.

We can construct an NFA for this language by mimicking the regular expression
$$ (a+b)^* + (a+c)^* + (b+c)^*. $$
The NFA contains four states: an initial state $q_0$ which leads, via $\epsilon$-transitions, to three other states, all accepting: one $q_1$ with self-transitions labeled $a,b$, another $q_2$ with self-transitions labeled $a,c$, and the final one $q_3$ with self-transitions labeled $b,c$.

We can think of the NFA as "guessing" which of the letters is missing. If it guesses that $c$ is missing, then it transitions to the state $q_1$; if it guesses that $b$ is missing, then it transitions to the state $q_2$; and if it guesses that $a$ is missing, then it transitions to the state $q_3$. In the remainder of its run, it verifies this guess. If it manages to scan the entire input without seeing the guessed missing letter, then the word is accepted.